# Python social auth error in facebook

Tags: django, facebook, python-social-auth

I am using python social auth in django. While using facebook an error occured.

[http://solarbiz.in/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=FV9GiLjcd8BQHN3fhuneiowJlnS6PQO8&error_code=100&error_message=Invalid+Scope%3A+profile&state=FV9GiLjcd8BQHN3fhuneiowJlnS6PQO8](http://solarbiz.in/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=FV9GiLjcd8BQHN3fhuneiowJlnS6PQO8&error_code=100&error_message=Invalid%20Scope%3A%20profile&state=FV9GiLjcd8BQHN3fhuneiowJlnS6PQO8)

Any suggestions please, I am a beginner in django. I tried for several hours on this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link provided, error message is:

```
error_message   u'Invalid Scope: profile'
```

make sure you are using latest SDK and change the scope from `profile` to `public_profile`

Comment: i am using python social auth 0.2.1 which is the latest one and i also put  SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE=['email','public_profile'] but  that doesnot help

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `settings.py`, it says:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'profile']
```

I guess you should restart your web-server if you already had updated the file.